# Rails: How to display users having specific criteria in search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When User ABC clicks on the "Search" link, I want ABC to see only those members who live in the same city as ABC. Right now I have the following code in the index action of the Users controller, which displays all the members registered on the website. I am also using `will_paginate` gem for pagination.

```
  def index
    @users = User.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  end
```

In the view, I am iterating through the `@users` array to display all users.

However, I want ABC to only see members from his/her city. Once ABC can only see members from his/her city, I am going to implement filters to further narrow the results. But that is a later step. Also, ABC should not be able to see profiles of users from other city by simply typing their username in the address bar. How do I do this?

Comment: How you store the city in User model?

Comment: Ivan already answered. I hope that will resolve your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use ActiveRecord scopes ([Ruby on Rails Guides / ActiveRecord Query Interface)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Then in your User model you will have something like this:

```
scope :living_in_the_same_city_with, lambda { |user| /* your where condition where(:city_id => user.city_id) */ }
```

And inside controller:

```
@users = User.living_in_the_same_city_with(current_user).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am sure this is the solution but I am not able to get the where condition correct. I have a Users model which has_one Profile and the profile has a city column as a string. I am having an issue with the where condition: where(:city => user.profile.city) and its giving me an error. It says that "column users.city does not exist"

Comment: Her is my latest code : 

lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profile => {:city => user.profile.city} ) }

Comment: This works just fine (pay attention that where condition specifies **profiles**, not **profile**): `scope :living_in_the_same_city_with, lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profiles => {:city => user.profile_city}) }`. Also `user.profile.city` is a direct violation of the _Law of demiter_ ( [wiki Law of Demiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) )